# Hide columns on command

Tags: c#, wpf

I posted  a question regarding displaying two columns using lambda in WPF, although I received excellent suggestions, I believe that I was trying to make things more complicate so I am taking a different approach.
My Silverlight business application populates a `datagrid1` using

```
DBDomainContext context = new DBDomainContext();

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = context.DBTables;
context.Load(context.GetDataBasesQuery());
```

The `GetDataBasesQuery()` method is defined in the domainservices.cs as follows:

```
public IQueryable<DBTable>GetDataBases()
 {
 return this.ObjectContext.DBTables;
 }
```

This populate the `datagrid1` with 10 column, `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`

And I can hide the columns as follows:

```
void DGPro_AutoGeneratingColumnForDB(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
 {
if (e.PropertyName == "col1")
                e.Cancel = true;

if (e.PropertyName == "col2")
                e.Cancel = true;

}
```

How can I hide them based on user input?
I would like to use a checkbox for users to select col1 or col2 to hide.
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't auto generate the columns, build them yourself and then you can access them by name and hide/show them as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @DonA's good suggestion a bit, you could try changing your auto generation event handler to this:

```
private void DGPro_AutoGeneratingColumnForDB(object sender, 
DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Name = e.PropertyName;
}
```

Then using the names of the properties/columns, you should be able to simply call:

```
var column = dataGrid.Columns.First(c => c.Name = "col1");
column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapse;
```

Unfortunately, I've not been able to test this, so it *might* not work.

Comment: What part of it didn't work? Did the columns get named OK? Did the call to `First` throw an `Exception` saying that there were no items in the sequence?

Comment: I changed the auto generation handler did not recognized the property “Name” in 
e.Name = e.PropertyName;

then 
changed “Hide” to collapse because Hide was not recognized
var column = dataGrid.Columns.First(c => c.Name = "col1");
column.Visibility = Visibility.Collapse;
May be this is due to Silverlight business application and C#

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me about this... I've updated my answer for future users... what did you set instead of the `Name` property? Did could try the `Tag` property.